# Signed int not being converted into unsigned int

Tags: c++

I am reading the book C++ Primer, by Lippman and Lajoie. On page 65 they say:
*If we use both unsigned and int values in an arithmetic expression, the int value ordinarily is converted to unsigned.*

If I try out their example, things work as expected, that is:

```
unsigned u = 10;
int i = -42;
std::cout << u + i << std::endl; // if 32-bit ints, prints 4294967264
```

However, if I change i to -10, the result I get is 0 instead of the expected 4294967296, with 32-bit ints:

```
unsigned u = 10;
int i = -10;
std::cout << u + i << std::endl; // prins 0 instead of 4294967296. Why?
```

Shouldn't this expression print `10 + (-10 mod 2^32)` ?

Comment: `4294967296 == 2^32`, and `2^32 mod 2^32` is `0`.

Comment: You need to take the result of `+` (on unsigned integers) mod 2^width as well.

Comment: Oh... so I need to take the mod 2^width again? That part I don't understand very well. If I'm already converting the signed into unsigned, and the entire expression yields an unsigned, why do I need to "wrap" the result again?

Comment: Ok... now I see it. The result doesn't fit into an unsigned, so the final result is "wrapped" again. Should I delete the question before it's filled with downvotes? Thank you for your help.

Comment: `-10` is first promoted to `unsigned`, yielding `4294967286`. `4294967286 + 10` is `4294967296`, which is `2**32`, which is out of range for `unsigned`, so unsigned integer overflow happens and you end up with `0`.

Comment: `-10` when converted to a 32-bit `unsigned` will have a value of `4294967286` (after applying modulo arithmetic).  So `u + i` is computed as `10 + 4294967286` which is *mathematically* `4294967296`.   But that value exceeds the maximum value a 32-bit `unsigned` can represent, so modulo arithmetic has an effect again, giving a result of `0u`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both `unsigned int` and `int` take up 32 bits in the memory, let's consider their bit representations:

```
unsigned int u = 10;
00000000000000000000000000001010

int i = -42;
11111111111111111111111111010110

u + i:
11111111111111111111111111100000
```

If we treat `11111111111111111111111111100000` as a signed number (`int`), then it is -32:
[image]

If we treat it as an unsigned number (`unsigned`), then it is 4294967264:
[image]

The difference lies in the highest bit, whether it represents -2^31, or +2^31.

---

Now let's take a look at `(10u) + (-10)`:

```
   unsigned int u = 10;
   00000000000000000000000000001010

   int i = -10;
   11111111111111111111111111110110

   u + i:
(1)00000000000000000000000000000000
```

Since `u + i` will be over 32 bits limit, the highest bit `1` will be discarded. Since the remaining 32 bits are all zero, the result will be 0. Similarly, if `i = -9`, then the result will be 1.